# Storing big numbers in BitSet for easy lookup

Tags: java, data-structures, bitset

I want to parse files and read numbers which are stored as Strings and build the data structure to store the numbers.

Later in my application should provide method to check if a number is present in the list of numbers. These numbers will not fit into one long, but all the number can be represented with maximum of 512 bits.

I don't need to perform any maths operations on these number, but only search the presence of number.

Thought of storing the numbers in *BitSet* so that we can reduce the memory usage, but Maximum size of the *BitSet* is limited by MAX_SIZE of the *Integer* . Is there a better way to store the numbers for lookup?

Comment: You don't need `BitSet` of size bigger than MAX_SIZE, you only need `new BitSet(512)`

Comment: I need to store list of numbers, not just one number.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class?

Comment: I need to just check presence of a number, so need not store all the numbers.